# Delete multiple users in the database using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to NodeJS.I was trying to create an api which will delete multiple users in a single go.I know how to delete single rows/user but getting stuck at multiple ones.

This is what i have done for a single user

```
var User = require('../models/User');
var moment = require('moment');
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
var config = require('../config');


function createJWT(user) {
  var payload = {
    sub: user._id
    , iat: moment().unix()
    , exp: moment().add(14, 'days').unix()
  };
  return jwt.encode(payload, config.TOKEN_SECRET);
}

exports.createUser = function (req, res, next) {
  var user = new User(req.userData);
  user.save(function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message
      });
    }
    if(result.status == 'unverified')
      return next();
    else
      res.send({
        token: createJWT(result),
        user : user
      });
  });
};

exports.removeUser = function(req, res){
  User.findById(req.params.id).remove(function(){
    res.redirect('/');
  });
};
```

Can anyone help me out with this.

Comment: You could create a loop depending on the number of params given and then execute the query (slightly modified tho) which you've already used.

Comment: You can delete all users by dropping the database :P But in all seriousness, if you want to delete them by ID, you should just use a loop and call the function to delete a single user.

Comment: Or use [`User.remove()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.remove) which actually takes a query in argument.  If that is the question then it's been answered long ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a simple way to do it.You can use '**IN**' operator directly on model

```
User.remove({'_id':{'$in':[array_of_id]}})
```

Note: You shouln't use loop for delele, it's not a good practice.

> [Mongoose - Model.remove](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.remove)

Comment: Whats the best way to delete multiple Users in node if you can help me out

Comment: Before deleting, you can create an array of user_id's which needs to be deleted. If it depends on some condition then you can first query a database for such list. this will be lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

> suppose you have an array of userIDs say uidArr

**first method**

```
User.remove({'_id':{'$in':uidArray}})
```

**second method using async flow library**

```
const async=require('async');
async.forEach(uidArray, function (uid, callback) {
  User.findById(uid).remove(function(err){
  err ? callback(err) : callback(null);
  });
  },function(err) {
    if (err)
      return res.status(400).send(err);
    else
     return res.redirect('/');
  });
```

Comment: I didnt think you can pass an array to req.params, or at least I don't know how.  You can pass it through a post body, and retrieve it from req.body.array.  But, assuming you get an array or user ids, iterating through it to delete each one makes sense to me.

Comment: Right..we can't pass array to req.params,though we can pass through req.query or req.body.. so i updated the answer removing the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

By the look of it, I am guessing you are using `mongoose`?

Anyway if you use `User.remove({_id: req.params.id})` where the object inside the remove is the query that will apply. `req.params.id` is a array of user_ids.

`Remove` in mongo removes all records that match your query. This also applies if you are using the mongo driver with using `db.User.remove({})`. Btw according to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/remove-documents/) you could use `deleteMany` to run your query

**UPDATE**
Sagar's solution is absolutely correct. If you are looking into deleting multiple IDs you could use the `$in` and if you're looking into deleting records in different attributes you can use the `$or` query